# How to pass 2 variables from jquery AJAX to ASP.Net WebApi2 method?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api2

I can write a JQuery AJAX call to a webapi2 (asp.net) controller with only 1 parameter just fine (one json object), but when attempting to send 2 parameters (a string and an integer) to a call with all else remaining the same, I get

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

error in the browser console.  I believe I've tried every combination I can think of to get 2 parameters to pass, but always end up with the same error message!  I'm not sure of the correct format for the data: in javascript - I thought I made a JSON object, but did not. I've quoted, unquoted, and tried every combination I can think of, but no joy. Does ASP.Net WebAPI2 not accept more than 1 parameter? (I'm converting ASMX from an old site to api controllers and am stuck on 1 particular one that takes 2 parameters - works fine for ASMX, but webapi doesn't seem to recognize the signature).

web method in C# (i've tried the post, put and delete verbs - no joy)

```
    [Route("api/DeleteUserSearch")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin,paid,vendor,visitor")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUserSearch(string userid, int usersearchidx)
    {
        int retval = 0;
        if (IsValidUserId(userid))
        {
            retval = (await userSearch_Data.DeleteSavedSearchAsync(userid, usersearchidx)).xToInt();
        }
        return Ok(retval);
    }
```

The AJAX call: (one version that worked with ASMX)

```
function deleteUserSearch(uid, sid) {
$.ajax({
    url: '../../api/DeleteUserSearch',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'post',
    data: { userid:  uid , usersearchidx : sid },
    success: function (data) {
        //refresh searches dropdown
        ShowSuccessMsg('Your search has been deleted.');
        $('#SSPopup').modal('hide');
        RetrieveSearchesDD(uid, "#ddlSavedSearches", false, "")
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log('Error (deleteUserSearch): ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }
});
};
```

This works for all other calls with 1 parameter (any object), but does not for more than one. What am I doing wrong here?

Full Error in the Console: (it's obviously a signature problem - the URI is correct).

```
Error (deleteUserSearch): {
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "{\"Message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44371/api/DeleteUserSearch'.\",\"MessageDetail\":\"No action was found on the controller 'SavedSearches' that matches the request.\"}",
  "responseJSON": {
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44371/api/DeleteUserSearch'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'SavedSearches' that matches the request."
  },
  "status": 404,
  "statusText": "error"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution1

**Get data as one object and one parameter from form**

When you are passing data as an object like `{ userid: uid, usersearchidx : sid }` you need some changes in your `Controller` and `Action`

```
public class Parameter
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserSearchIdX { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUserSearch([FromForm] Parameter param)
{
    // Your code
}
```

#### Solution2

**Get data as two parameters separately**

If you can't change the old code too much and you want to get two parameters separately, then you can do it like this:
There is no change in your API:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUserSearch(string userid, int usersearchidx)
```

And you can send your parameters like a query string:

```
function deleteUserSearch(uid, sid) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../../api/DeleteUserSearch?userId=' + uid + '&userSearchIdX=' + sid,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'post',
    //data: { userid: uid, usersearchidx: sid },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log('Error');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention - this is DotNetFramework 4.72

Answer (score 0):

OK. Got it figured out. WebApi can only handle one parameter, but it can be anything (an object).
Because this is DotNetFW 4.72 , the [Form] decorator won't work (DotNetCore only), so I figured I'd just create a JSON object in Javascript and match it with an object in C#.

(I have a class/model called UserSearch with the properties UserId and UserSearch_Idx)

So the working version code is as follows:

```
    [Route("api/DeleteUserSearch")]
    [HttpDelete]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin,paid,vendor,visitor")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUserSearch(UserSearch p)
    {
        int retval = 0;
        if (IsValidUserId(p.UserId))
        {
            retval = (await userSearch_Data.DeleteSavedSearchAsync(p.UserId, p.UserSearch_Idx)).xToInt();
        }
        return Ok(retval);
    }
```

On the client side, it's straightforward: Just create a JSON object and assign it's properties.
Code on that end looks like so:

```
function deleteUserSearch(uid, sid) {
    var uSearch = {};
    uSearch.UserId = uid;
    uSearch.UserSearch_Idx = sid;

    $.ajax({
        url: '../../api/DeleteUserSearch',
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'delete',
        data: uSearch,
        success: function (data) {
            //refresh searches dropdown
            ShowSuccessMsg('Your search has been deleted.');
            $('#SSPopup').modal('hide');
            RetrieveSearchesDD(uid, "#ddlSavedSearches", false, "")
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log('Error (deleteUserSearch): ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
    });
};
```

Thank you Saeid for the tip (Core has a built in object representing the form data - which is nice)!